# Id outside of view hierarchy used as container for FragmentTabHost.setup()?

Tags: android, android-view, fragment-tab-host

I was reviewing the sample project for the support v4 package and stumbled upon something weird.:

**R.id.fragment1** is used as a container for **mTabHost** during setup in **FragmentNestingTabsSupport.java**.
Shouldn't it be an id corresponding to a view that is inside the `FragmentActivity`'s view hierarchy?

All I see is that its view hierarchy is made of a single `FragmentTabHost`.

BTW: fragment1 is present inside `fragment_hide_show_support.xml`, which is part of a different demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shouldn't it be an id corresponding to a view that is inside the
>   FragmentActivity's view hierarchy?

Not quite. If you look at the source code for the `FragmentTabHost` class you'll see that the `FragmentTabHost` will use the provided id **only when the container, which will hold  the content, doesn't already exist**. This doesn't happen in that sample as the constructors of `FragmentTabHost` call a private method which has the task of building a layout(including the above content container) file if the `FragmentTabHost` doesn't contain a `TabWidget`.

So in that sample the `FragmentTabHost` doesn't contain a `TabWidget` which triggers a layout to be built. Having this built layout means the id provided to the `setup()` method is ignored. They might as well simply call `mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager());` .

Comment: Thank you! I wish they had made that sample the way you said so people don't get confused.